# Sum and Grouping from Different Tables

Tags: mysql

I got three tables.

```
Table (Store)
+-----+-----+
| ID  | Qty |
+-----+-----+
| 001 |   4 |
| 002 |   3 |
| 003 |   5 |
| 004 |   6 |
+-----+-----+

Table (Received)
+-----+-----+
| ID  | Qty |
+-----+-----+
| 001 |   2 |
| 005 |   9 |
| 001 |   5 |
+-----+-----+

Table (Issued)
+-----+-----+
| ID  | Qty |
+-----+-----+
| 001 |   3 |
| 003 |   2 |
| 001 |   1 |
| 005 |   2 |
+-----+-----+
```

I want to sum the quantity from (Store + Received) - Issued, group by ID 
I want the result to be as shown below. Please help.

```
Table (Stock)
+-----+-----+
| ID  | Qty |
+-----+-----+
| 001 |   7 |
| 002 |   3 |
| 003 |   3 |
| 004 |   6 |
| 005 |   7 |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as

```
select 
x.id , coalesce(sum(qty),0)-coalesce(i_qty,0) from
(
 select id,qty from store
 union all 
 select id,qty from received
)x
left join(
 select id,sum(qty) as i_qty 
 from issued group by id
)y on x.id = y.id
group by id
```

Comment: Hi Chakraborty, how to achieve the same result without using union operator.

Comment: There is nothing wrong using `union all` and let me know why you do not want union all in the query ?

Comment: I am using a code generator in which it does not supports union and Stored procedure calls.

Comment: Sorry but this kind of operation can not be done just using join, since even with left join if some ids are not present in the left table will be eliminated in the result. So `union all` makes sure that all the ids are present. And I am surprised the union is not supported in the code generator. Is it some framework ?

Comment: What if my Store Table contains all the ID's. Can we use join without using union all?

Comment: Yes in that case its possible.

Comment: Thanks Chakraborty, problem solved by creating Custom Views from MySQL